regex back reference
I have a large text file with many extraneous newlines \r\n. I wish to replace each of these immediately following a letter in the range a-z with that letter followed by a blank space. Using notepad++ the regex [a-z]\r\n finds this combination all right, but I have not been able to determine the correct replacement expression. For example the file contains Indian\r\n which I would like to replace with Indian followed by a blank.
This has been done in the above description of my problem.
Example:
Copy the following text into notepad++:

He glanced at his watch another two hours to go.
He went over in his mind all that had appeared in the papers about
Indian
Island.

Hit ctrl H to bring up the replacement dialog.
In the lower left hand corner select regular expression.
Find what: [a-z]\r\n
Replace with: ([a-z])
Clicking on Find next results in highlighting of the final n in Indian and the next two spaces
for the invisible carriage return and line feed. Clicking on Replace results in replacing the n with [a-z] and \r\n with a blank.
I thought placing parentheses around [a-z] would back reference the letter particular letter n found, and yield simply n followed by a blank.
Note: There is an invisible blank after ([a-z]) in the Replace with: box.
Note: Since there is a period and not a letter preceding the \r\n in the first line, this is skipped over.

You do not capture when finding, so you cannot backreference! Find: ([a-z])\r\n and replace with $1  .

Find: ([a-z])\r\n and Replace with:  $1. The $1 in the replacement expression represents your first captured group. You can also use \1  if you are familiar with this usage from other regex flavors.
The documentation gets a little complex but here is a link to the relevant page: npp-user-manual#regular-expressions.
